# Picking up an item from a list of lists

Tags: python, list

I'm pretty new in python and have am difficulty doing the next assignment.
I am receiving a list of lists with numbers and the word none, for example:

```
 [[1,None],[2,4],[1.5,2]]
```

My problem is when I go through None (I need to sum up the lists) I need to replace it by the max number in the same place in the other lists.
So my result should be `None = max(4,2)` and receive :

```
 [[1,4],[2,4],[1.5,2]]
```

If I go through a for loop I don't understand how can I go to the other sub lists and check them out (especially when I don't know how many subs lists I have)

Comment: is that a string containing the word `'none'` or `None` as in `NoneType` in python

Comment: Are you saying that every time None appears, it always get replaced by the max number in all lists?

Comment: None = nonetype not string, every None gets replaced by the max of the sub lists in the same place (there could be a none in the other places )

Comment: My initial objective for this program is to sum up the every sub lists and the function needs to return the lowest one

Comment: Edit your question to show the loop you wrote and describe what part works and where it doesn't.  As it is, you are asking for your homework to be done for you.  In the abstract, you loop through your data ... and if your data is a list you can loop through it ... and you can test what data you have as you are iterating.

Comment: No i just asked how can i got to other sub lists when i am in a for loop

Comment: Please [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234) an answer if you think it solves your problem. It will community at large to recognize the correct solution. This can be done by clicking the green check mark next to the answer. See this [image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png) for reference. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Use a nested list comprehension with conditional

```
>>> l =  [[1,None],[2,4],[1.5,2]]
>>> def findMax(j):
...     return max(i[j] for i in l)
... 
>>> [[j if j is not None else findMax(k) for k,j in enumerate(i)] for i in l]
[[1, 4], [2, 4], [1.5, 2]]
```

Here the list comprehension checks if each element is None or not. If not it will print the number, else it will fnd the maximum and print that element.

Another way using `map` is

```
>>> l =  [[1,None],[2,4],[1.5,2]]
>>> maxVal = max(map(max, l))
>>> [[j if j is not None else maxVal for k,j in enumerate(i)] for i in l]
[[1, 4], [2, 4], [1.5, 2]]
```

Comment: `j!=None` -->  `j is not None`

Comment: Interesting solution, but probably over OP's head seeing as stated as new to python :)

Comment: @cricket_007 Haha, fair enough. It will be helpful in 2 ways. 1. The OP will learn some new stuff 2. Others will be interested in it (just like you are).

Comment: Would it be possible to adjust this so the `findMax` wouldn't be called every time `None` is found?

Comment: @cricket_007 Yep. By putting the max of all in a list. That's not difficult to do. I guess you got the idea.

Comment: Yeah, I got the idea. I made an edit that is more Pythonic

Comment: Yeah i need to understand now how that is working for a beginner :)

Comment: @Macsim Read the explanation. If you still did not understand I will add more

Comment: Well i looked at it for like 1 hour till i got it, made me learn couple of things, not sure i will be able to write like this in the near future, maybe later.thank you for your suggestion

Comment: @Macsim Glad to be of help. Please [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234) an answer if you think it solves your problem. It will community at large to recognize the correct solution. This can be done by clicking the green check mark next to the answer. See this [image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png) for reference. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a hint: In Python, a for in loop iterates through all the elements in some iterable. If you have a list of lists, that means each element in the list can also have a for loop applied to it, as in a for loop inside a for loop. You could use this if and only if the maximum depth of a list is 2:

```
def get_deep_max(deeplst):
   new = []
   for elem in deeplst:
      for num in elem:
         new.append(num)
   return max(new)
```

Try writing the code for replacing the none value yourself for practice.

Comment: Yeah i understand the fundamental usage of for loops, my problem is mainly when i am in a for loops in the going through a sub list, stop the count of the for and go to other sub lists in the meanwhile.

Answer (score 1):

Code:

```
for idx1, sublist in enumerate(list1):
    for idx2, element in enumerate(sublist):
        if element is None:
          try:
             sublist[idx2] = max(list1[idx1+1])
          except IndexError:
             pass
```

The problem is that if there is a None in the last list you didn’t specify what the code should do. I just added a `try` and  `except`. You can replace `pass` with what you want the code to do.

Comment: Yeah it is a None not a string. tnx

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion:

```
x = [[1,None],[2,4],[1.5,2]] #your list
highest_num = None  # assume that 0 can be the highest number in a different situation
for each in x:`# find the highest number
   for another in each:
        if another > highest_num:
            highest_num = another
for each in xrange(len(x)): # find the None and replace it with the highest number
    for another in xrange(len(x[each])):
        if x[each][another] is None:
            x[each][another] = highest_num
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from contextlib import suppress


l = [[1,None],[2,4],[1.5,2]]

for sub in l:
    with suppress(ValueError):
        i = sub.index(None)  # find index of None in sublist (or ValueError)
        sub[i] = max(s[i] for s in l if s[i] is not None)  # replace sublist item with max of sublists in same index
        break

print(l)
# [[1, 4], [2, 4], [1.5, 2]]
```

Comment: Well thank you i did not know about the "suppress"  action

Answer (score 1):

This one is a bit cleaner to read than the others IMO

```
l = [[1,None],[2,4],[1.5,2]]
maxVal = max(map(max, l)) # maps the function 'max' over all the sub-lists
for subl in l:
    for idx,elem in enumerate(subl): # use enumerate to get the index and element
        if elem is None:
            subl[idx] = maxVal
print l
# [[1, 4], [2, 4], [1.5, 2]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my suggestion:

```
l = [[1, None], [2, 4], [1.5, 2]]
# l = [[1, None], [2, 4], [1.5, 2]]
l1 = zip(*l)
# l1 = [(1, 2, 1.5), (None, 4, 2)]
m = map(max, l1)
# m = [2, 4]
l2 = [map(lambda y: m[i] if y is None else y, x) for i,x in enumerate(l1)]
# l2 = [[1, 2, 1.5], [4, 4, 2]]
ret = zip(*l2)
# ret = [(1, 4), (2, 4), (1.5, 2)]
```

Comment: Yes, `zip()` is a built-in function in python: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip